# Shell (sh) script array

Tags: arrays, sh, ash

Have been trying to find away to do array in sh shell script.  Other than BASH etc. have not found much, other than arrays not supported in sh.

Here's what I've come up with using setvar and eval.  Is there a better way?  Any way to eliminate setvar and/or eval?

```
#!/bin/sh
# FreeBSD 11.1

# Kind of an array workaround.

echo -e "Simulated array creation and element assignment using dynamic index."
array() {
    i=0
    for x in $2
    do
        setvar ${1}_${i} $x    # any way to do without setvar?
        i=$((i+1))
    done
    setvar ${1}_cnt $i
}

array "my_arry" "a b c"

echo -e "\nSimulated array element access using dynamic index."
i=0
while [ $i -lt $my_arry_cnt ]
do
    eval aev=\${my_arry_${i}}    # any way to do without eval?
    i=$((i+1))
    echo $aev
done

echo -e "\nSimulated array element access using static index."
echo ${my_arry_0}
echo ${my_arry_1}
echo ${my_arry_2}
```

Comment: What is `setvar`? It certainly isn't a POSIX shell command.

Comment: Like anything involving `eval`, this isn't going to be safe for general data. Use a language with proper data structures if you need arrays, not `sh`.

Comment: setvar is a built-in sh command.
Per the FreeBSD sh manual page:
setvar variable value
Assigns the specified value to the specified variable.  The setvar command is intended to be used in functions that assign values to variables whose names are passed as parameters. In general it is better to write ``variable=value'' rather than using setvar.

Comment: Adding the `ash` tag, as that is the shell you are really using. `setvar`, like arrays themselves, aren't generally available via `/bin/sh`.